# Else without if, but really unclear why, also another error I'd like looking at

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Hey guys working on a Java assignment for uni, why doesn't this work?

```
    if ( i <=39998)
        String digit = pictureFile.substring(i, i+1);
    else 
        String digit = pictureFile.substring(39998,39999);
```

It comes up with this error message:
[image]

Comment: Please post your error message as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: And show more pertinent code. One rule of thumb I follow: put **all** blocks in curly braces, `{` and `}`, even one line blocks as it will save your tail at one point or another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have written is a syntax error, because an `if` or `else` without a code block in curly brackets can only take a statement, not a variable declaration.

This would compile, but is pointless:

```
if (i <=39998) {   // WARNING: unused variable
    String digit = pictureFile.substring(i, i+1);
} else {
    String digit = pictureFile.substring(39998,39999);
}
```

It makes no sense to declare the variable inside of the branches, as it is not visible outside the `if`. Should be

```
String digit;
if ( i <=39998)
    digit = pictureFile.substring(i, i+1);
else 
    digit = pictureFile.substring(39998,39999);
```

or

```
String digit = (i <= 39998)
     ?  pictureFile.substring(i, i+1)
     :  pictureFile.substring(39998,39999);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the JLS that states that the compiler must raise a compile error?

Comment: @hexafraction [*"Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block."*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) is the simplest quote.